# Flask app rendering some variable urls from HTML docs in folder but not others HTML docs in the same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

My Flask app renders all templates in the template folder, including all blog posts in a blog folder within the templates folder. However, I have the exact structure for my app's glossary as I have for the blog - a folder called 'glossary' within the templates folder. But, it's quirky. It renders some html documents but not others from that same folder. It renders 0-day.html every time I click a link with that dynamic url or directly type in /0-day; but not act.html using /act. I have 180 html files in the glossary folder and about half render and the rest return a 404.

I've been researching this for a month now, and today I switched the glossary structure by creating a blueprint instead. I used this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WteIH6J9v64. I got everything running as normal, except the same issue with the glossary persists with the blueprint setup as well.

Assuming everything else works, and it does:

## Glossary Term:

```
@glossary.route("<termname>", methods=["POST","GET"])
def term(termname='story'):

    try:

        visits(termname)

        return render_template(f"{termname}.html", glossary=True, termname=termname)

    except Exception as e:

        return page_not_found(e)
```

As you can see below, I have my blog setup the same way:

## Blog Posts

```
@app.route("/blog/<postname>", methods=["POST","GET"])
def post(postname='distant-idealism-introduction'):

    try:
        visits(postname)

        return render_template(f"/blog/{postname}.html", blog=True, postname=postname)

    except Exception as e:
        return page_not_found(e)
```

The only difference is that the blog is routed from the routes.py now and the glossary terms from the glossary.py blueprint. However, when there was no blueprint I was rendering everything from the routes.py file, so the blueprint setup is not the cause.

I apologize, but because this problem is so confusing, I don't know what else to add. It's even difficult to research because I always get results like the YouTube video above - either about blueprints, building routes, or something Flask in general. I never get any search result even close to my issue. If more info is required just let me know, please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems I found:

1. The URL rule is missing a start slash:

```
@glossary.route("/<termname>", methods=["POST","GET"])
```

2. Since your templates about glossaries were put in a `glossary` folder, your template path should be `/glossary/act.html`:

```
return render_template(f"/glossary/{termname}.html", glossary=True, termname=termname)
```